# JQuery: Restrict input characters to 0-9

Tags: jquery, validation

When the user presses a key, I want to remove characters that are not in the range 0-9, but this code isn't working: ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JXYbC/2/))

```
$('input').on('keypress', function(event){
        var char = String.fromCharCode(event.which)
        var txt = $(this).val()
        if (!txt.match(/^[0-9]*$/)){
            var changeTo = txt.replace(char, '')
            $(this).val(changeTo).change();
        }
});
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: I think that using JQuery Validation (http://jqueryvalidation.org/) plugin you can do it better...

Comment: `keypress` event is fired before value is change - that's why `txt` will not include the new value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/JXYbC/3/

```
$('input').on('keypress', function(event){
    if (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57)
        return false;
});
```

But as Mikk3lRo pointed out, there are much better answers already on stackoverflow, because you should for example also allow the delete key, so the user can correct an input:

[How to allow only numeric (0-9) in HTML  inputbox using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995183/how-to-allow-only-numeric-0-9-in-html-inputbox-using-jquery)